# How to hide GNOME panels?

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel

I want to hide ubuntu panels completely in my ubuntu 10.10. Is there a way to do this via gconf-editor? So that I can retrieve it later if I need.

I don't prefer to use auto hide option. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run gconf-editor(press alt+f2 and type gconf-editor)

Browse to "/desktop/gnome/session/required_components" and change the value of "panel" from gnome panel to awn or docky or you can try to leeav it empty but i'm not sure if it works.

The log out and log in!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the panel and select properties. There are options for autohide or using the hide buttons. If you want to completely remove the panel just right click and select delete.

Comment: You can't delete the panel if you have only one by doing this.

Comment: @Thomas If you only have one panel yes you don't want to delete it but if you wanted to delete the bottom panel and use docky or awn.

Comment: The original poster wants to get rid of all of the panels, and when you try to delete the last remaining panel the "Delete This Panel" option is grayed-out, unclickable.